# How to use reduce/inject in Ruby without getting Undefined variable

Tags: ruby, reduce

When using an accumulator, does the accumulator exist only within the `reduce` block or does it exist within the function?

I have a method that looks like:

```
 def my_useless_function(str)
   crazy_letters = ['a','s','d','f','g','h']
   str.split.reduce([]) do |new_array, letter|
     for a in 0..crazy_letters.length-1
       if letter == crazy_letters[a]
         new_array << letter
       end
     end
   end

   return true if (new_array == new_array.sort)
 end
```

When I execute this code I get the error

```
"undefined variable new_array in line 11 (the return statement)"
```

I also tried assigning the `new_array` value to another variable as an `else` statement inside my `reduce` block but that gave me the same results.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Block local variables

`new_array` doesn't exist outside the block of your `reduce` call. It's a ["block local variable"](http://jacopretorius.net/2012/01/block-variable-scope-in-ruby.html).

`reduce` does return an object, though, and you should use it inside your method.

```
sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce(0){ |acc, elem| acc + elem }
puts sum
# 6
puts acc
# undefined local variable or method `acc' for main:Object (NameError)
```

## Your code

Here's the least amount of change for your method :

```
def my_useless_function(str)
  crazy_letters = ['a','s','d','f','g','h']
  new_array = str.split(//).reduce([]) do |new_array, letter|
    for a in 0..crazy_letters.length-1
      if letter == crazy_letters[a]
        new_array << letter
      end
    end
    new_array
  end

  return true if (new_array == new_array.sort)
end
```

Notes:

- `return` isn't needed at the end.
- `true if ...` isn't needed either
- `for` loop should never be used in Ruby
- `reduce` returns the result of the last expression inside the block. It was `for` in your code.
- If you always need to return the same object in `reduce`, it might be a sign you could use [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).
- `"test".split` is just `["test"]`

[String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html) and [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html) have methods that could help you. Using them, you could write a much cleaner and more efficient method, as in [@Phrogz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43811412/6419007).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `new_array` is created during the call to `reduce`, and then the reference is lost afterwards. Local variables in Ruby are scoped to the block they are in. The array can be returned from `reduce` in your case, so you could use it there. However, you need to fix a couple things:

- `str.split` does not break a string into characters in Ruby 2+. You should use `str.chars`, or `str.split('')`.
- The object retained for each new iteration of `reduce` must be retained by returning it from the block each time. The simplest way to do this is to put `new_array` as the last expression in your block.

Thus:

```
def my_useless_function(str)
   crazy_letters = ['a','s','d','f','g','h']
   crazy_only = str.split('').reduce([]) do |new_array, letter|
     for a in 0..crazy_letters.length-1
       if letter == crazy_letters[a]
         new_array << letter
       end
     end
     new_array
   end

   return true if (crazy_only == crazy_only.sort)
end
```

Note that your function is not very efficient, and not very idiomatic. Here's a shorter version of the function that is more idiomatic, but not much more efficient:

```
def my_useless_function(str)
   crazy_letters = %w[a s d f g h]
   crazy_only = str.chars.select{ |c| crazy_letters.include?(c) }
   crazy_only == crazy_only.sort # evaluates to true or false
end
```

And here's a version that's more efficient:

```
def efficient_useless(str)
   crazy_only = str.scan(/[asdfgh]/) # use regex to search for the letters you want
   crazy_only == crazy_only.sort
end
```

Comment: Nice, I was about to write a more efficient version but it would have been very similar to yours. Note that to check if an array is sorted, you don't need to sort it (e.g. you could use `each_cons` instead)

Comment: @Eric, maybe Ruby could use `class Array; def sorted?: enum = self.to_enum; loop { return false if (enum.next <=> enum.peek) == 1 }; true; end; end; [1,2,3].sorted? #=> true; [1,3,2].sorted? #=> false` (or use `each_cons`, as you suggested).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `Array#sorted?` would be a perfect candidate for a C function with a basic loop.

Comment: @Eric, even in Ruby a simple loop would work fine, but some of us have been reprogrammed to not think that way.